# malloc using 4 bytes for char

Tags: memory, alignment, malloc

I am writing a code to examine how memory is managed between stack and heap. for a course work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define NUM_OF_CHARS 100


// function prototype
void f(void);


int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}

void f(void)
{

    char *ptr1;
    ptr1 = (char *) malloc(NUM_OF_CHARS * sizeof(int));
    printf("Address array 1: %016lx\n", (long)ptr1);


    char *ptr2;
    ptr2 = (char *) malloc(NUM_OF_CHARS * sizeof(int));
    printf("Address array 2: %016lx\n", (long)ptr2);

}
```

when I run this code I get the following:

```
Address array 1: 000000000209e010
Address array 2: 000000000209e1b0
```

my expectation was to see a difference in the address of 100 bytes, but the difference is 416 bytes, when I changed the NUM_OF_CHARS to any other value (200,300,...) the result was always (NUM_OF_CHARS*4 + 16), so it seams like malloc is allocating 4 bytes for each char rather one byte plus 16 bytes of some overhead.

can anyone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory allocation is platform/compiler dependent. The only thing `malloc` ensures is that it **allocates enough memory for what you are asking** and nothing more.

There is no guarantee that your addresses will be contiguous due to [memory alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Also, you are allocating by size of `ints` and not `char` in your code. This is most likely the reason why you see a `NUM_OF_CHARS*4` difference, while the remaining difference can be attributed to padding.